# How to archive and extract a .tar.gz file

Tags: gzip, tar, solaris-10

A simple question. On x86 Solaris 10, I tried the following to compress a folder(Data) of files.

```
tar -cvf /path/to/Data/* | gzip > /path/to/archive/Data.tar.gz
```

Now, I can list the file names and their sizes using:

```
gunzip -c Data.tar.gz
```

However, when I try to uncompress(for validation) Data.tar.gz:

```
gzip -d Data.tar.gz
tar -xvf Data.tar
```

I get a "checksum error"

Can someone please suggest the correct way to compress and extract files in Solaris 10. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You can do **archive** in 2 steps:

```
$ tar cvf archive.tar file* 
$ gzip archive.tar
```

(It will create archive.tar.gz, while removing archive.tar.)

**Extraction** also in 2 steps:

```
$ gunzip archive.tar.gz
```

(It will create archive.tar and remove archive.tar.gz.)

```
$ tar xvf archive.tar
```

---

To list files inside the .gz file:

```
gzip -l archive.tar.gz
```

---

Alternatively, you can use 7zip which put together all files as well as compress them.

```
7z a archive.7z Makefile* (to create archive)
7z l archive.7z           (to list files inside the archive)
7z e archive.7z           (to extract)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're piping (as you should), you need to use `-` to indicate stdin or stdout.  E.g.

```
tar -cvf - data/* | gzip > data.tar.gz
gzip -dc data.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
```

Comment: Still getting the following error when I try to extract it back: "tar: directory checksum error". Please advice, thanks

Comment: The above works for me.  Are you doing something with the .tar.gz file in between?  Are the commands being run on different machines?

Answer (score 3):

You have to direct the output of tar cvf to stdout, to be able to read it with gzip:

```
tar cvf - <path> | gzip > <file>
```

In general is also recommended to use relative path names. Using a path starting with / can cause problems if you want to unpack it on another system. gnu tar will transform absolute paths into relative. gnu tar also accepts a compression option, so gzip is no longer necessary:

```
gnutar cvfz <file> <path>
```

In addition you could do something like:

```
tar cvf - <path> | ssh remotehost (cd <another dir>; gzip > <file>)
```

which will change the directory before zipping.

The manual page of Solaris tar, has more examples. See man tar(8).